# How an account balance is calculated?

Tags: accounts

I can see that each account [keeps it's balance of lumens](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/accounts.html#balance). Yet there should be a place where the rest of assets that belong to an account is preserved - the [API for Account Details](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/accounts-single.html) returns a list of these.

My question is how heavy is that operation? Is the data come from the database (where it's indexed properly) or there is a need to look into the XDR files, by a chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each account trustline is represented as a record in a `trustlines` table located in the Core database. The trustline itself has a `balance` field that contains current asset balance for that account.

"Find asset balance for the account" is rather cheap operation considering that the query involves a simple join over `trustlines` and `accounts` tables on indexed fields.

If you need to query this information very often, consider running your own Core node (in no-validation mode in case of limited resources). In that way you will be able to get data directly from DB, omitting the penalty of serialization/deserialization and network lag in the case of Horizon API query.